# How to access/open arbitrary formatted (.pdf etc) documents from R's console?

Tags: r, pdf, manual

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Writing-package-vignettes states:

"*...In addition to the help files in Rd format, R packages allow the inclusion of documents in **arbitrary other formats.** The standard location for these is subdirectory **inst/doc** of a source package, the contents will be copied to subdirectory **doc** when the package is installed. Pointers from package help indices to the installed documents are automatically created. Documents in inst/doc can be in arbitrary format, however we strongly recommend providing them in **PDF** format, so users on almost all platforms can easily read them...*"

I used `roxygen` package. It produced .Rd files for me. I produced .pdf of my package via " `R CMD Rd2pdf causfinder/`" from Windows command line **(** or, via during build/install process via "`roxygenize("causfinder")`; `build("causfinder")`; `install("causfinder")`".**)**

I wanted to add some supplementary .pdf help files (that I created outside of R; from Word via save as .pdf etc.) to my package other than the one that is produced via above techniques. These supplementary .pdf files include the detailed mathematical theory and lots of samples of the functions of my package which illustrate the usage of the functions via various plots, graphs, etc. I called it TheoryOfcausfinder.pdf.

I wanted to add this supplementary .pdf file to my package. As is directed from R's above manual, I put TheoryOfcausfinder.pdf to inst\doc folder in my R's working directory. Upon build/install process, I obtained causfinder/doc/index.html and causfinder/doc/TheoryOfcausfinder.pdf in my R's library location.

The content of index.html:

*"...Vignettes from package 'causfinder': The package contains no vignette meta-information.*
*Other files in the doc directory: TheoryOfcausfinder.pdf..."*

I want the future users of causfinder to easily access/open this supplementary TheoryOfcausfinder.pdf. (I will add that there is such a file in functions' help documents)

Is there a way to open/access TheoryOfcausfinder.pdf in R's library location from (within) R's console?

*(Important: By the way, since I am novice of Sweave and knitr, I do not wanna enter that path! 
I look for a solution outside Sweave and knitr.)*

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have found another solution or not yet, but I am posting some possible ideas below.

source http://www.r-bloggers.com/show-me-the-pdf-already/

```
# under Unix types
pdf <- getOption("pdfviewer", default='')
f <- system.file("doc", "TheoryOfcausfinder.pdf", package = "causfinder")
system2(pdf, args = f)
```

source http://www.r-bloggers.com/show-me-the-pdf-already/

```
# under MS Windows
f <- system.file("doc", "TheoryOfcausfinder.pdf", package = "causfinder")
shell.exec(normalizePath(f))
```

source [Opening PDF within R studio using file.show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791493/opening-pdf-within-r-)  studio-using-file-show/33791818

```
# under OS X
f <- system.file("doc", "TheoryOfcausfinder.pdf", package = "causfinder")
system2('open', args = f, wait = FALSE)
```